# Normal Class, singleton class or static methods for performance

Tags: java, android

In my application I've a class called `AppUtils.java`, which basically contains utility functions like `covertDpToPx() ,`UrlEncoder()` etc.

Issue is this class, apart from normal `Activities`, can also be called by `Services` running constanly in background.

So, how should I design this class from performance point-of-view?

*Thank You*

Comment: It's hard to tell from a *performance* point of view without seeing some code, but it's unlikely to be the biggest factor here. The question is, do those functions do anything which require or would be suited to an instance?

Comment: make sure to take race conditions into consideration

Comment: It depends on many factors. Do you need access to shared resources? If those classes can be static without any multithreading problems, then I think static methods are not a problem and probably will be fastest solution with least overhead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The good practice for an utility class is to make it final to disable inheritance, make constructor private to prevent instantiation and provide a set of public static utility methods:

```
public final class AppUtils {

    private AppUtils() {
    }

    public static float covertDpToPx() {
        ...
    }

    public static String encodeUrl(String url) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [Android Performance Tips](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html#PreferStatic) Google recommends static over singleton or virtual for android

Answer (score 1):

If possible, make all methods static and just in case declare the constructor private so you don't accidentally create an instance of the class.